# Command Timeout, longer to get response back

Tags: c#-4.0

I am executing large query,so my app throwing time out error. Some of the thread suggested to added command time out but after adding those lines it take longer to get response back, any idea why or what am i missing in my code?

```
 public int CreateRecord(string theCommand, DataSet theInputData)
    {

        int functionReturnValue = 0;
        int retVal = 0;

        SqlParameter objSqlParameter = default(SqlParameter);
        DataSet dsParameter = new DataSet();

        int i = 0;

        try
        {
            //Set the command text (stored procedure name or SQL statement). 

            mobj_SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
            mobj_SqlCommand.CommandText = theCommand;
            mobj_SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



            for (i = 0; i <= (theInputData.Tables.Count - 1); i++)
            {
                if (theInputData.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dsParameter.Tables.Add(theInputData.Tables[i].Copy());
                }
            }
            objSqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@theXmlData", SqlDbType.Text);
            objSqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            objSqlParameter.Value = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>" + dsParameter.GetXml();
            //Attach to the parameter to mobj_SqlCommand. 
            mobj_SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(objSqlParameter);
            //Finally, execute the command. 
            retVal = (int)mobj_SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            //Detach the parameters from mobj_SqlCommand, so it can be used again. 
            mobj_SqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();


            functionReturnValue = retVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new System.Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Clean up the objects created in this object. 
            if (mobj_SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                mobj_SqlConnection.Close();
                mobj_SqlConnection.Dispose();
                mobj_SqlConnection = null;
            }
            if ((mobj_SqlCommand != null))
            {
                mobj_SqlCommand.Dispose();
                mobj_SqlCommand = null;
            }
            if ((mobj_SqlDataAdapter != null))
            {
                mobj_SqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
                mobj_SqlDataAdapter = null;
            }
            if ((dsParameter != null))
            {
                dsParameter.Dispose();
                dsParameter = null;
            }
            objSqlParameter = null;
        }
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
```

Comment: It is correct. When you get tesponce within 30 secs your session is just aborted and timeout reported. Now it works 2 minites.

Comment: Maybe you could add a dummy select / data retrieving first so that the caller receives something back. The ideea is that the timeout is counted from the time that you initiate the SqlCommand call to the time that you receive some data from that call. Or, just increase the timeout :)